# PHP GET url iframe

Tags: php, url, iframe, get

I have:

```
<?php
$goto = $_GET['goto'];
?>
```

and:

```
<form method="get"><input type="text" name="goto" id="goTo" /></form>
<iframe id="page" src="http://<?php echo $goto; ?>"></iframe>
```

If I go to my page, nothing displays unless I end the URL with `?goto=<webadress>`.

Example: `http://example.com/windows8/apps/Flake/index.php?goto=http://google.com`

How can I make it so that if the user didn't type in `?goto=http://google.com`, the page displays like a backup website?

Comment: In addition to Jon's answer, you need to add a submit button to your form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to provide a default value for `$goto`, do it like this:

```
<?php
$goto = !empty($_GET['goto']) ? $_GET['goto'] : 'http://www.google.com'; // default here
?>
```

However, you should be aware that by doing this, you allow everyone to construct URLs that point to your server but output to the browser HTML (and more importantly, scripts) that is not under your control (it comes from whatever URL `goto` points to). This would make it trivially easy for someone to attack your users.

Comment: Yeah, I just love this. Answers to stupid questions get most upvotes. We have a problem here, *StackExchange*!

Comment: Thank. But I solved it another way! :P I'm making a "web-browser" for my Windows 8 Mimic :) http://enji.se/windows8/ But thnx anyways! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$goto = isset($_GET['goto']) ? $_GET['goto'] : "backup page";
```